# Toggle a class on an element click in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In **angular.js** how can I toggle a css class `active` on and off on click of the element? I know I can use `ng-class` and `ng-click` but how do I reference itself? For example, let's say I have three buttons:

```
<a class="btn" ng-click="" ng-class"">First</a>
<a class="btn" ng-click="" ng-class"">Second</a>
<a class="btn" ng-click="" ng-class"">Third</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a ng-click="firstActive = !firstActive" ng-class"{'btn':true, 'active':firstActive}">First</a>
<a ng-click="secondActive = !firstActive" ng-class"{'btn':true, 'active':secondActive}">Second</a>
<a ng-click="thirdActive = !firstActive" ng-class"{'btn':true, 'active':thirdActive}">Third</a>
```

You'll have to have separate scope variables in your controller for firstActive, secondActive, and thirdActive, all set to false by default.

Comment: Is there a way without explicitly setting all these flags and polluting the controller?

Comment: I don't see it as "polluting" the controller. The controller is supposed to hold display logic and data linkage, and that is exactly what this is. If you don't want to do it this way, try using the Angular-UI buttons.